# How to stack y-axes in ChartJS when datasets and scales are added dynamically?

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

I have a form that is filled out by the user with three selection menus which control what data is displayed on the graph. When an item from the dropdown menu is selected, the graph builds the dataset and the y-axis for it on the fly. The problem I'm having is when I try to use the `stack` property in the `options.scales.[scaleId]` namespace. To explain, let me use an example. I have these three select menus:

1. First Variable (line chart)
2. Second Variable (line chart)
3. Outage Type (line chart with categories on the y-axis)

The user must select the first variable before the second variable or outage type menus will show. The first variable is plotted with the y-axis on the left, extending the full height of the chart. If the user chooses to add the second variable, it is plotted with the y-axis on the right which also extends the full height of the chart. If the user then chooses to add an outage type, multiple datasets are returned and each dataset has it's own y-axis value that is charted on the left y-axis. I want the outage type datasets to stack on top of the first and second variable datasets. Instead what happens is the second variable y-axis moves up. The data is confidential so I can't share the axes outright, but in this picture, the y-axes on the left stack appropriately (the first variable's y-axis is in red, the outage y-axis stacks on top in blue). The second variable y-axis is in black and you can see that it's shifted upward instead of letting the outage "ghost" y-axis stack on top (I'll talk about what I mean in a second):
[image: Graph with messed up y-axes]

Here's is how I have the datasets and chart options defined, edited for brevity. Please make sure to read the lengthy comment above scale `y4` as it explains what I meant earlier about a "ghost" scale:

```
//First dataset
  const datasets = [{
      label: getLabel(firstVariable, vList, 'legend'),
      order: 1,
      backgroundColor: 'blue',
      borderColor: 'black',
      data: y1Data,
      yAxisID: 'y1'
    },
  ]

//Default chart options - this is what is rendered upon choosing first variable
const options: ChartOptions<'line'> = {
  scales: {
    x: {
      //stuff here
    },
    y1: {
      title: {
      display: true,
      text: getLabel(firstVariable, vList, 'axis'),
      position: 'left',
      stack: 'stack',
      stackWeight: 2
    },
  },
}

//Second dataset added dynamically
if (secondVariable != null && secondVariable != 'None'){
  const y2Data = getData(filteredTSData, secondVariable, unit)
  datasets.push({
    label: getLabel(secondVariable, vList, 'legend'),
    //This dataset should draw last
    order: datasetCounter != 1 ? datasetCounter + 1: 2,
    backgroundColor: 'orange',
    borderColor: 'black',
    data: y2Data,
    yAxisID: 'y2'
  })
  options['scales'].y2 = {
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: getLabel(secondVariable, vList, 'axis'),
      position: 'right',
    },
    stack: 'rightStack',
    stackWeight: 2,
    grid: {
      drawOnChartArea: false,
    }
  }
}

//Outage types added dynamically
if(outageType != null && outageType != 'None') {
  if(gadsChartDatasets.length > 0){
    gadsChartDatasets.forEach((gadsDS) => {
      datasets.push({
        label: gadsDS['label'],
        order: gadsDS['order'],
        backgroundColor: gadsDS['backgroundColor'],
        borderColor: gadsDS['borderColor'],
        data: gadsDS['data'],
        //gadsDS['yAxisID'] evaluates to y3
        yAxisID: gadsDS['yAxisID']
      })
    })
    options['scales'].y3 = {
      type: 'category',
      labels: yAxisLabels,
      position: 'left',
      stack: 'leftStack',
      stackWeight: 1,
      offset: true,
    }
    //This is an axis that is not displayed or associated with data, it is simply used to make the right
    //y-axis (second variable) even in height with the left y-axis (first variable) rather than extending into the outages part of the chart at the top
    options['scales'].y4 = {
      display: false,
      position: 'right',
      stack: 'rightStack',
      stackWeight: 1,
      offset: true
    }
  }
}
```

I have stepped through in the debugger to ensure the order of the datasets being drawn is correct. I think my problem is the order in which the *scales* are being added to the chart options. If I select a first variable, then select an outage type, then go and select the second variable to display, the y-axes stack appropriately:
[image: Properly stacked y-axes]

**How do I dynamically stack the y-axes?**